# Fitting a subset model with just one lag, using R package FitAR

Tags: r, time-series

I am trying to fit a subset model with only lag 4. In the manual it's written "you must use `p=c(0,0,0,4)` since
`p=4` will fit a full `AR(4)`".

I did this.

```
#fit a subset model with just lag 4
Fit=FitAR(p=c(0,0,0,4), lag.max = "default", ARModel = "ARz")
```

However, I get the following error message:

```
Error: p > 0 are not all TRUE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
GetFitARpMLE(z,4)
```

You will get

```
> GetFitARpMLE(z,4)
$loglikelihood
[1] -2350.516

$phiHat
       ar1        ar2        ar3        ar4 
 0.0000000  0.0000000  0.0000000 -0.9262513 

$constantTerm
[1] 0.05388392
```